# Has the latest Codenameone build version lost functionality to scroll through container of rows containing

Tags: codenameone

We have 4 containers in an array, we show the first perfectly, but when we set as current the next container to show it, we call `forceRevalidate()` on it but only the most general container is showed.
When i update the project libraries through Codename One Settings -> Basic -> Update Project Libs and clean&build project the error persist.

#Versions.properties

Comment: Not intentionally. An update was pushed to maven not to Ant. If you're using ant then you wouldn't see the latest version. If you use maven you can try different versions to see if there was a regression in Codename One.

Comment: this project use a ant->build.xml what its the solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

It hasn't changed locally for a while since we didn't push an update for Ant in ages. I suggest migrating to maven where you can check such functionality.

Notice that if this applies only to device builds those do get updated for Ant and will be consistent with the latest maven version.

Comment: I migrated the act project to maven with the migration tool from the codename one documentation, when importing to netbeans and compiling the project mvn clean install passes the tests wth SUCCESS
but it does not generate an apk with mvn cn:build -P android

giving error in console with mojo plugin:
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'cn' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the r

Neither using maven projects does the Codename One option appear to generate the online apk

Comment: I had less luck with the migration tool and better one with a clean https://start.codenameone.com/ project. Notice that you need to select NetBeans there to generate the right project format since there are some minor configuration differences.

Comment: How to generate the apk of the project within netbeans ide?

Comment: With cloud build or locally?
If locally you will need to open Android Studio for the final stage. If using the cloud you can send a build to the servers that will deliver an APK for you.

Comment: I don't see the option codename one -> send android build, in codenameone projects with maven and initializr in nebeans ide 8.2, only those that are ant.

Comment: See this: https://shannah.github.io/codenameone-maven-manual/ the option is different per IDE but it's in the maven build area now.

Comment: Tanks, in the manual the process is 1-mvn clean install 2-mvn cn1:build -Dcodename1.platform=javase -Dcodename1.buildTarget=android-device                               But i send to the server cloud of codenameone and generate error log, i share the error log

Comment: [link](https://ufile.io/dqp0t546)

Comment: i find solution -Dcodename1.platform=javase for -Dcodename1.platform=android but the error with the refresh containers not solutionated !

Comment: With maven you can set the Codename One version to any previous version and see if this was working on an older version. Assuming that it was you can tell us the exact version when it was working and when it stopped.. We can then review the diff between the versions and understand the root cause.

Comment: I was trying several versions and in all of them the same thing happens, the containers are not refreshed correctly.
The link from where I check the maven versions https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.codenameone/codenameone-maven-plugin

Comment: Then this is probably unrelated to a Codename One version and might be related to a bug in your application. If it's something that's inconsistent enable the EDT violation detection mode and see if it finds a problem.

Comment: the edt violation for testing in simulator or testing apk in android? In the documentation it mentions [link](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/detect-edt-violations.html)

Comment: This is in the simulator only, not on the device.

Comment: but the refreshment in the containers and the disappearance of the menu button does not occur in the simulator only in the apk on mobile

Comment: Sure. But if there's an EDT violation it might be detectable on the simulator. Might only happen on the device because of a race condition.

Comment: Testing the containers and buttons in application in the simulator, it does not seem to show a problem related to the refreshment of the containers in console, with EDT active.

Comment: In that case we'll need some test case to reproduce the problem.

Comment: any test like which one?

Comment: Something that will reproduce the problem you're experiencing that you can attach to an issue. So not the full application.